# Ruby: Why does Hash === {} return true?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash, let's say:

```
ahash = {test1: "test1", test2: "test2"}
```

Why is it that `Hash === ahash` returns true, but `ahash === Hash` doesn't? Is this some default ruby behavior with === and class name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's just how the `===` method works. It's directional and that applies to any class:

```
"foo" === String
# => false
String === "foo"
# => true
```

This is because that evaluates to:

```
"foo".send(:===, String)
String.send(:===, "foo")
```

Those are two different methods, one for the class, one for the instance.

If you're only concerned with class information:

```
"foo".is_a?(String)
# => true

{ }.is_a?(Hash)
# => true
```

This method makes it a lot more clear what your intention is.

Comment: great identation on my previous comment...
show-method Hash#===  and ahash.=== shows me the same C method.
Although no one said that method was about obj equality.

Comment: @AlexandreAbreu, it would be kinder to the reader to say, "if anyone is interested in reading the C source code for `Object#===`, they can find it here.", with a link.

Comment: Sorry, that was bad...  'show-method' is a pry method.
 github.com/pry/pry

Answer (score 6):

### You Aren't Testing What You Think You're Testing

[Module#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (also called the "case equality operator") returns true if the object on the right-hand side of the expression is an instance of the left-hand side, or one of its descendants. When you ask:

```
Hash === {test1: "test1", test2: "test2"}
```

what you're really asking is this: "Is this hash literal an instance or descendant of the Hash class?" On the other hand, the reverse is not true, since the [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) *class* is not an instance or descendant of your hash literal.

### More About Case Equality

On the other hand, the following works either way:

```
Hash.new === {}
{} === Hash.new
```

because both expressions are case-equivalent. Here's the same result using your data:

```
Hash[:test1, "test1", :test2, "test2"] === {:test1=>"test1", :test2=>"test2"}
#=> true

{:test1=>"test1", :test2=>"test2"} === Hash[:test1, "test1", :test2, "test2"]
#=> true
```

However, threequals isn't just a stand-in for [Object#is_a?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F). It's really meant to be consumed by case/when statements, and [Giles Bowkett says](http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2007/11/what-is-threequals.html):

> The === method exists for controlling how a case/when block will evaluate an object. It should never be used by humans. It is code written to be consumed by other code, specifically, by case and when.